# Separating out posts from friends, groups, and pages on Facebook

Tags: facebook

Is there a way to setup Facebook so that in my default stream I only see posts from my friends?  I get so many things popping up from pages and organizations that I've liked as well as posts to groups I belong to that it's hard to even find my friends' posts.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Facebook offers no easy way to do that. You do have a few options, however, even if they are cumbersome.

1. Click the `Following` dropdown from a friend’s profile page, and click **See First**. Now, whenever that friend posts a new update, you will always see it at the top of your feed. This can be done for Pages as well as actual friends.
2. Open your Friends list by navigating to your profile, then click the tab that reads `New Posts`. From here you can access all of your friends who have posts updates you haven’t seen yet.
3. Create a custom list of friends by navigating to your “[list of friends lists](https://www.facebook.com/bookmarks/lists/).” Click `Create List` and add your friends into it. Now if you open that list instead of the default Facebook feed, you will only see posts from the people in that list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prioritize whose post you want to see first.

From [Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/371675846332829):

> **How can I view and adjust my News Feed preferences?**
>
> Your News Feed preferences help you control what you see on your News Feed.
>   To view your News Feed preferences:
>
> 1. Click account settings in the top right corner of any Facebook page (example: your home page).
> 2. Select **News Feed Preferences**.
>
> To adjust your News Feed preferences:
>
> - Click **Prioritize who to see first** to make posts from people or Pages appear at the top of your News Feed. Learn about [see first](https://www.facebook.com/help/1188278037864643?helpref=faq_content).

If you don't want see someone's post but want to be connected, just unfollow them.

> - Click **Unfollow people to hide their posts** to unfollow a person, Page or group. Learn about [unfollowing](https://www.facebook.com/help/276458109035418?helpref=faq_content).
> - Click **Reconnect with people you unfollowed** to follow a person, Page or group that you unfollowed in the past. Learn about [reconnecting](https://www.facebook.com/help/146865632052048?helpref=faq_content).
> - Click **Discover Pages that match your interests** to find Pages you may want to see in News Feed. Learn about [liking Pages](https://www.facebook.com/help/216630288356463?helpref=faq_content)
> - Click **See more options** to see which apps you've hidden from News Feed.
>
> Learn how to switch from [top stories to most recent stories](https://www.facebook.com/help/218728138156311?helpref=faq_content) on your News Feed.